# ¿Cómo puedo exportar un Formview con datos a excel, word o PDF?

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, asp.net, postgresql

soy nuevo en estos rumbos, lo que necesito saber como se exportaria un formview a excel, word o pdF?

ayudaaa u.u

Comment: Si te refieres a los datos de un GridView, hay una gran cantidad de tutoriales.

Comment: nope, no es de un Gridview y si he visto que hay bastante tutorial sobre ello, pero en este caso es desde un Formview que contiene datos.